# How to select a nested field with bigrquery using dplyr syntax?

Tags: r, google-analytics, dbplyr, unnest, bigrquery

I'd like to explore a Google Analytics 360 data with `bigrquery` using `dplyr` syntax (rather than SQL), if possible. The gist is that I want to understand user journeys—I'm interested in finding the most common sequences of pages at the user level (even across sessions).

I thought I could do it this way:

```
sample_query <- ga_sample %>%
  select(fullVisitorId, date, visitStartTime, totals, channelGrouping,
  hits.page.pagePath) %>% 
  collect()
```

But I get an error that `hits.page.pagePath` was not found. Then I tried:

```
sample_query <- ga_sample %>%
  select(fullVisitorId, date, visitStartTime, totals, channelGrouping, hits) %>% 
  collect() %>% 
  unnest_wider(hits)
```

But the result is `Error: Requested Resource Too Large to Return [responseTooLarge]`, which makes perfect sense.

From what I've gathered, with the SQL syntax, the workaround is to `unnest` remotely, and `select` only the `hits.page.pagePath` field (rather than the entire `hits` top-level field).

E.g., something like this (which is a different query, but conveys the point):

```
SELECT
  hits.page.pagePath
FROM
  'bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20160801' AS GA,
  UNNEST(GA.hits) AS hits
GROUP BY
  hits.page.pagePath
```

Is it possible to do something similar with `dplyr` syntax? If it's not possible, what's the best approach with SQL?

Thanks!

**Update: Actual query/code**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
fullVisitorId, visitId, date, visitStartTime, hits.page.pagePath, hits.time, geoNetwork.networkDomain
FROM 'bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*' AS GA, UNNEST(GA.hits) AS hits
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20191101" AND "20191102"
AND geoNetwork.networkDomain NOT LIKE "%google%"
```

Comment: Do you have the bigquery code/syntax that would execute your query?

Comment: Hey @Simon.S.A.: I've added the full query at the end of the question.

Answer (score 4):

The kinds of queries `dbplyr` can create when translating from R to BigQuery (or whatever database language you are using) depends on the translations that have been defined between R and BigQuery. I can not find any example that suggests a translation is defined for `UNNEST` in the existing `dbplyr` package. [Reference 1](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/sql-translation.html), [Reference 2](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/translate_sql.html)

One work around is to define a custom function, not to do translation within `dbplyr`, but as a translator alongside `dbplyr`. I have used this approach with success before when I needed `PIVOT` in SQL but could not find a translation for `tidyr::spread`.

The approach works, because remote tables in `dbplyr` are defined by two things: (1) the connection to the remote database, (2) the code/query that returns the current view of the table. Hence once `dbplyr` has translated R to BigQuery or SQL it is updating the second half of the definition.

**We can do this using a custom function:**

```
unnest <- function(input_tbl, select_columns, array_column, unnested_columns){

  # extract connection
  db_connection <- input_tbl$src$con

  select_columns = paste0(select_columns, collapse = ", ")
  unnested_columns = paste0(paste0("un.", unnested_columns), collapse = ", ")

  # build SQL unnest query
  sql_query <- dbplyr::build_sql(
    con = db_connection
    ,"SELECT ", select_columns, ", ", position, ", ", unnested_columns, "\n"
    ,"FROM (\n"
    ,dbplyr::sql_render(input_tbl)
    ,"\n) AS src\n"
    ,"CROSS JOIN UNNEST(", array_column, ") AS un WITH OFFSET position"
  )

  return(dplyr::tbl(db_connection, dbplyr::sql(sql_query)))
}
```

Note that I am a `dbplyr` user, but not a BigQuery user, so my syntax in the above may not be quite perfect. I have followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40792981/unnest-expression-references-column-which-is-neither-grouped-nor-aggregated?rq=1) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53635020/bigquery-argmax-is-array-order-maintained-when-doing-cross-join-unnest) for syntax.

**Example use:**

```
remote_table = tbl(bigquery_connection, from = "table_name")
unnested_table = unnest(remote_table, "ID", "array_col", "list")

# check syntax of dbplyr query
unnested_table %>% show_query()
# if this is not a valid bigquery query then next command will error

# view top 10 rows
unnested_table %>% head(10)
```

If `remote_table` looks like:

```
ID ARRAY_COL
01 list = [a,b,c]
02 list = [d,e]
03 list = [q]
```

Then `unnested_table` should look like:

```
ID POSITION un.list
01    0        a
01    1        b
01    2        c
02    0        d
02    1        e
03    0        q
```

And `unnested_table %>% show_query()` should look something like:

```
<SQL>
SELECT *, position, un.list
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM table_name
) AS src
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(ARRAY_COL) AS un WITH OFFSET position
```

#### Update to match target query

I am aware of no `dbplyr` feature that will translate `_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20191101" AND "20191102"` easily so you will have to handle this another way - perhaps looping over a list of dates in R.

First step is to get `dbplyr` to render the query prior to unnesting. Probably something like:

```
for(date in c("20191101", "20191102")){
    table_name = paste0("bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_",date)

    remote_table = tbl(bigquery_connection, from = table_name)

    remote_table = remote_table %>%
        filter(! (geoNetwork.networkDomain %like% "%google%")) %>%
        select(fullVisitorId, visitId, date, visitStartTime, hits, geoNetwork.networkDomain) %>%
        distinct()
}
```

Calling `show_query(remote_table)` should then produce something equivalent to the following. But it will not be exactly identical because `dbplyr` writes code differently to humans.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT fullVisitorId, visitId, date, visitStartTime, hits, geoNetwork.networkDomain
FROM 'bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20191101'
WHERE NOT(geoNetwork.networkDomain LIKE "%google%")
```

The second step is to call the custom unnest function"

```
remote_table = unnest(remote_table,
                      select_columns = c("fullVisitorId", "visitId", "date", "visitStartTime", "geoNetwork.networkDomain"),
                      array_column = "hits",
                      unnested_columns = c("page.pagePath", "time")
               )
```

Calling `show_query(remote_table)` should then produce the following:

```sql
SELECT fullVisitorId, visitId, date, visitStartTime, geoNetwork.networkDomain, position, un.page.pagePath, un.time, 
FROM (

the_query_from_the_first_step

) AS src
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(src.hits) AS un WITH OFFSET position
```

That is probably as far as I can assist as I do not have a bigquery environment to test this in myself. You may have to adjust the custom `unnest` function to get it to exactly match your context. Hopefully the above is enough to get you started.

Comment: Hey @Simon.S.A.: I tried pasting the unnest function in R and got a few errors that I couldn't quickly fix (I don't know much about functions). I'll try a few fixes and send you a screenshot with the errors.

Comment: There is a close quote missing before the "\n" fixed above.

Comment: What's your environment like? I now get `"Error: unexpected string constant in:
"    ,"\n) AS src\n"
    ,"CROSS JOIN UNNEST(", array_column ") AS un WITH OFFSET position""`

Comment: There was a comma missing after `array_column` and before `")...` fixed above

Comment: Thanks! The function works but when I try it with actual BigQuery fields, I get an error: `object 'position' not found.

Not sure if you want to take a stab with the Sandbox:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/sandbox

Comment: Sounds like my attempt to include the offset failed. I recommend you remove "WITH OFFSET position" from the end of `sql_query` and remove `position, ", ",` from the start of `sql_query` this should remove the offset functionality from the custom function.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comment, the function given by Simon.S.A. doesn't work (valiant attempt, but was not familiar with bigquery).

I made some alterations to create a function that does work with a single nested variable.

```r
library(magrittr)
library(tidyverse)
library(dbplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dbplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     ident, sql
library(bigrquery)

bq_deauth()
bq_auth(email="your_email@domain.com")

bq_conn = dbConnect(
  bigquery(),
  project = "elite-magpie-257717",
  dataset = "test_dataset"
)

df = tibble(
  chr =   c(1,1,1,2,2,3),
  start = c(0, 10, 12, 0, 5, 1),
  end =   c(2, 11, 15, 1, 8, 3)
)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>% mutate(range = list(seq(start, end)))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Rowwise: 
#>     chr start   end range    
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <list>   
#> 1     1     0     2 <int [3]>
#> 2     1    10    11 <int [2]>
#> 3     1    12    15 <int [4]>
#> 4     2     0     1 <int [2]>
#> 5     2     5     8 <int [4]>
#> 6     3     1     3 <int [3]>

df %>%
  rowwise() %>% mutate(range = list(seq(start, end))) %>%
  unnest(range)
#> # A tibble: 18 x 4
#>      chr start   end range
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#>  1     1     0     2     0
#>  2     1     0     2     1
#>  3     1     0     2     2
#>  4     1    10    11    10
#>  5     1    10    11    11
#>  6     1    12    15    12
#>  7     1    12    15    13
#>  8     1    12    15    14
#>  9     1    12    15    15
#> 10     2     0     1     0
#> 11     2     0     1     1
#> 12     2     5     8     5
#> 13     2     5     8     6
#> 14     2     5     8     7
#> 15     2     5     8     8
#> 16     3     1     3     1
#> 17     3     1     3     2
#> 18     3     1     3     3

dbWriteTable(
  bq_conn,
  name = "test_dataset.range_test",
  value = df,
  overwrite = T
)

df_bq = tbl(bq_conn, "test_dataset.range_test")

df_bq %>%
  mutate(range = generate_array(start, end, 1))
#> # Source:   lazy query [?? x 4]
#> # Database: BigQueryConnection
#>     end start   chr range    
#>   <int> <int> <int> <list>   
#> 1     2     0     1 <dbl [3]>
#> 2    11    10     1 <dbl [2]>
#> 3    15    12     1 <dbl [4]>
#> 4     1     0     2 <dbl [2]>
#> 5     8     5     2 <dbl [4]>
#> 6     3     1     3 <dbl [3]>

df_bq %>%
  mutate(range = generate_array(start, end, 1)) %>%
  unnest_wider(range)
#> Error: `x` must be a vector, not a `tbl_BigQueryConnection/tbl_dbi/tbl_sql/tbl_lazy/tbl` object.


my_unnest = function(input_tbl, array_column)
{

  ### extract connection
  db_connection = input_tbl$src$con

  ### column names surrounded by `` and separated by commas
  all_cols =
    colnames(input_tbl) %>%
    sprintf("`%s`", .) %>%
    paste(., collapse=", ")

  ### Build sql string
  sql_string =
    paste0(
      "SELECT ", all_cols,
      "FROM (", dbplyr::sql_render(input_tbl), ") ",
      "CROSS JOIN UNNEST(`", array_column, "`) AS `", array_column, "`"
    ) %>%
    str_replace("\n", " ")

  ### Build query object
  sql_query = dbplyr::sql(sql_string)

  print(sql_query)

  dplyr::tbl(db_connection, sql_query)

  return(dplyr::tbl(db_connection, sql_query))
}


df_bq %>%
  mutate(range = generate_array(start, end, 1)) %>%
  my_unnest("range")
#> <SQL> SELECT `end`, `start`, `chr`, `range`FROM (SELECT `end`, `start`, `chr`, generate_array(`start`, `end`, 1.0) AS `range` FROM `test_dataset.range_test`) CROSS JOIN UNNEST(`range`) AS `range`
#> # Source:   SQL [?? x 4]
#> # Database: BigQueryConnection
#>      end start   chr range
#>    <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
#>  1     2     0     1     0
#>  2     2     0     1     1
#>  3     2     0     1     2
#>  4    11    10     1    10
#>  5    11    10     1    11
#>  6    15    12     1    12
#>  7    15    12     1    13
#>  8    15    12     1    14
#>  9    15    12     1    15
#> 10     1     0     2     0
#> # ... with more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Note, it is important to make sure you specify the dataset in the connection (not just the project) or it will throw an error for missing dataset.

Furthermore, if you call the function `unnest` you will clobber `tidyr::unnest` which you may not want to do.